# Should I change the tag or request a tag change

Tags: discussion

I was going through post tagged as C++ and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28856010/4342498) post.  It is tagged as C++ but it only includes C code.  Should I change the tag or should I ask for the tag to be changed?

Comment: I'd say no to both, leave it as it is. Would that code not work in C++? The user probably tagged it with the language they're working in based on the compiler they're using -- just because they're not using the ++ features in this example of their code doesn't mean their question is incorrect in saying what language they're working in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just leave a comment that their code is C, and ask if they meant to tag it C++ or not. The OP might be compiling with a C++ compiler, or (in this specific case) submitting their code to an online judge that uses C++. It might be a relevant detail, so it's better to not just assume from the code which one is being used.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still new to the site so I want to make sure I am following proper procedure.